# Upgrade jQuery 1.8.3 to jQuery 1.9.0 raising Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating a website, and I used `jQuery 1.8.3` with `jQuery-ui 1.9.1`.
But for some reason, I need to upgrade to `jQuery 1.9.0`. I didn't change the jQuery ui version, and I have the following error :

> Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

The code raising this error is the following :

```
function displayEditPreferencesPopup(param1, param2)
{
    $("<div></div>")  
        .dialog({
            title: "My popup title",  
            modal: true,  
            height: 400,  
            width: 600,  
            left: 0,
            close: function () { 
                $(this).remove();
            },
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Edit Preference" : function() {
                    EditPreferences(); //Send some data to save in DB
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            }
        }).load('@Url.Action("Edit", "Preference")', { 'param1' : JSON.stringify(jsVariable1) , 'param2' : JSON.stringify(jsVariable2) });
        //last line is Razor syntax (ASP.NET MVC3 project), it corresponds to "/Preference/Edit" with parameters
}
```

So, this was perfectly working with `jQuery 1.8.3` but raises the error with `jQuery 1.9.0`.

I've seen [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520139/jquery-ui-dialog-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization), which seems very close to mine, but I'm unable to adapt the answer to my problem (I'm new with jQuery).

Can someone help me ?
Thank you