# JQuery Mobile 1.4 Close dialog programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Since JQM 1.4 has changed some widgets, in order to use "dialog" widget, there are 2 options:

1. data-role="page" data-dialog="true"
2. data-rel="popup"

I'm using first approach, so when user clicks "OK" button of my dialog, I update database and if all is ok, I would like to close the dialog.

As mentioned in [JQM doc](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/#method-close) I've tried using `$( ".selector" ).dialog( "close" )` but it throws `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`. Some example code:

**Dialog HTML**

```
<div id="manage-page" data-role="page" data-dialog="true" data-corners="false" data-close-btn="right" data-overlay-theme="b"> 
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Manage</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">  
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <input type="text" id="title" value=""/>
        <a href="#" id="saveTitle" data-role="button">Save</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Dialog JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveTitle', function(){
    var title= $('#title').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: CUSTOM_URL,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data != -1)
                $('#manage-page').dialog('close'); 
            else
                // Some stuff
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("ERROR saving title");
        }
    });
});
```

What is wrong? Thanks

**UPDATE**

I've solved using `data-rel="back"`in my open button and removing `$('#manage-page').dialog('close');`

Comment: your code is wrapped in `$(document).ready();` ?

Comment: Yeah. It works well in general (it's a very small piece of the whole project)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520139/jquery-ui-dialog-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization

Comment: I'm opening the dialog throw `$.mobile.changePage(domain() + '/private/manageDialog');` not using javascript.

Comment: use popup instead, dialog is deprecated and will be removed on 1.5

Comment: Mmmm regarding to jqm doc the dialog widget it's deprecated, that is `data-role="dialog"`... isn't it? I'm using `data-role="page" data-dialog="true"`.

Comment: @Fabien you mean to say adding data-rel="back" in your save button ?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the error. Your dialog code is ok, but you have to fix the way you use to *open* the dialog. You have to add the option:

```
$.mobile.changePage(domain() + '/private/manageDialog', {role:"dialog"});
```

Or add the `data-rel` property:

```
<a href="#manage-page" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

Comment: Your first option makes my dialog ugly (dialog's position changes, close button overlays, ...) and when I try closing the dialog I get blank page. Second one, I'm still getting the same error. Thanks!

Comment: uhm, it works in my test; the blank page seems like a page/hash problem. Can you try adding `data-history="false"` to your dialog?