# When I update to new jQuery my dialog throw error: cannot call methods on dialog prior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

When I update to new jQuery(v2.1) and jQuery UI (v1.11), I began to recieve error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close' 
Also, dialog.dialog stopped working overlay.

Code function:

```
function ShowPopup(element, restCon, restLay, url) {
$(element).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,

    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        dialogs.push(this);
        //other function
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog('destroy').empty();
        $(this).remove();
        //other function
    },
    width: 250,
    height: 320,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    title: "Show ",
    position: {
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: $("container")
    },
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
  });
  $(element).load(url, function () {
      //other element
  });
}
```

second function:

```
function CreatePopup(link, contId, restore, url) {
var target = $(link).not(".details-link");
if (target.length > 0)
{
    target.addClass("details-link");
    target.click(function(){
            ShowPopup(
                '#' + contId,
                restore,
                '<div id="'+ contId +'"></div>',
                url + $(this).attr('data-id')
            );
    });
 }
 }
```

call function:

```
$(function () {
    var count = '@Model.Count';

    setCountToSubTabjQuery($("#client-projects-@guid").closest(".tabs-  view").find('.tab-link.tab-link-project').children('.number'), count);

    CreatePopup('.project-Name',
                'project-info-details-popup-container-@guid',
                '#containerProject',
                '/Project/Details?id=');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="details-Item project-Name" data-id="@Model[i].ID">@Model[i].Project</div>
```

Comment: Update from which versions?

Comment: jquery: 1.5.1   ui: 1.8

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ui Dialog: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520139/jquery-ui-dialog-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization)

Comment: I delete duplicate setting dialogs, but problem is not solved

Comment: and I don't understand: Why overlay not working

Comment: Add more details about your html structure: basically we do not know what is `myDialog`, `modelTitle`, `id`...

Comment: We still miss some things: here you use `$('#add-edit-' + id)` but i cannot see any html item with `id='add-edit-1'`

Comment: add-edit-popup-container-@Model.Id. Where @Model.Id parametr, which comes Get request

Comment: Did you just read my comment? `add-edit-popup-container-@Model.Id` is not `add-edit-@Model.Id`. You create a dialog on something which is unknown for us, so we are not able to show you any clue in a jsfiddle for example (as you should have do initially, by the way).

Comment: sorry, edit html id. but don't work

Comment: here not clear html code. jsfiddle this code dont working

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't contain the lines that actually open your dialog, so my guess is that you're doing that somewhere else. That's most likely what leads to the error.

The problem is that you're calling `.dialog.destroy()` and `.remove()` in the `close` function handler. That call destroys the widget and removes the HTML element from the DOM. However, the HTML element is still alive in memory, since you're saving a reference to it in the variable `myDialog`. A subsequent call to `close` will then throw the exception you're receiving (or any widget method).

Here's a fiddle duplicating the problem; simply close the dialog and attempt to reopen it: http://jsfiddle.net/xsspx7d7/

Now, in order to handle this:

- The simplest workaround is to remove the variable `myDialog` entirely and just use the selector `$('#add-edit-' + id)` everywhere. That way, once the dialog was destroyed, the selector will simply not match anything, and not throw any errors.
- If you have the opportunity, a more flexible and resilient solution would be to rework the lifecycle of your dialog, and get the `close` handler to get rid of the `destroy` and `remove` function calls.

Comment: ok, but if ('#add-edit-' + id) passed as a parameter in function? And there also calling .dialog.destroy() and .remove() in the close function

Comment: Don't forget `$` -- the jQuery variable. `('#id')` returns a string, `$('#id')` returns the jQuery element selected by that string. Inside the `close` handler, though, you can just refer to it as `$(this)`

Comment: I using in my function just refer to it as $(this), but all the same not working.

Comment: What is doing? My function throw same exception

Comment: There's not enough information for me to be any more specific; perhaps you could edit the question to contain less boilerplate and more of the relevant callbacks