# JavaScript :- cannot call methods on A prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'resizeGrid'

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jqgrid

Well, I am trying to call a function that has object & method in 1 file to another file.

```
File 1 --
    var a ={
            resizeGrid : function(){
            //this manipulates the height & width of a grid
                                   }
           }
File 2 --
    var b ={
            manipulateGrid: function(){
            $('#containerGrid_0').a('resizeGrid');
                                      }
           }
```

I am trying to convert the older version of Jquery to the latest version ie. 1.7 to 2.2.2 using migrate plugin. Facing this issue `" cannot call methods on A prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'resizeGrid'"`

Tried some solution like below but didn't work.
 `$('#containerGrid_0').a().a('resizeGrid');`

For information look
[jquery ui Dialog: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520139/jquery-ui-dialog-cannot-call-methods-on-dialog-prior-to-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've provided, I can't tell exactly what your functions are doing, or how you are using them.  But here is an example of how to initialize them.

You can play with it by **clicking** here: [jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ky1m9ngx/1/)

```
$.fn.A = function(sFunc){
    var agrid = {
      resizegrid:function(ele){
        ele.append('<div>Hello</div>')
      }
    }
  agrid[sFunc](this)
};

$.fn.B = function(sFunc){
  var help = {
    checkResize:function(ele){
        ele.A('resizegrid')
    }
  }
  help[sFunc](this)
}

$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('body').B('checkResize')
})
```

Comment: Well, I am trying to call a function that has object & method in 1 file to another file.
File 1 -- 
var a ={
resizeGrid : function(){
//this manipulates the height & width of a grid
}
}

File 2 --
var b ={
manipulateGrid: function(){
$('#containerGrid_0').a('resizeGrid');
}
}